# I don't get what should be the C[_] type in Slick 2.1 Query class

Tags: scala, slick

I've just upgraded my Scala project to Slick 2.1 and I got a compilation error due to a change in Query class definition. It changed from `Query[+E, U]` to  `Query[+E, U, C[_]]`.

I have a method that takes as argument a Query type that I defined as `Query[Links,Link]` where `Link` and `Links` are defined as

```
case class Link( /* properties */)

class Links(tag: Tag) extends Table[Link](tag, "crawled_url") { /* methods*/ }
```

I don't get how to declare the C[_] type parameter in order to get my method to compile

```
def takeLimit(query: Query[Links,Link,??], limit: Int) = { /* do stuff */}
```

Here's the link to the source file of Query class in Slick's master repository

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/lifted/Query.scala

Comment: It is the type constructor for the unpacked collection type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C[_]` is the underlying collection type that slick will return.

It was added in 2.1.0: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0-RC3/upgrade.html

In your case you can probably change your method signature to this:

```
def takeLimit(query: Query[Links,Link,Seq], limit: Int) = { /* do stuff */}
```

Comment: Alternatively leave the collection type open: def takeLimit[C[_]](query: Query[Links,Link,C], limit: Int) = { /* do stuff */}

Comment: C is a higher kinded type by the way. A type parameter, that takes another type as its argument.